# Power consumption using FileWriter and accelerometer for Android

Tags: android, accelerometer, filewriter

I'm developing an Android app that samples data from the accelerometer for at least 6 hours. At the moment I write the data to a .txt file using FileWriter every time I sample from the accelerometer but this consumes a lot of power and heats up the phone. I have though about creating my own buffer and then only write to the .txt file every minute for instance.

What is the best way and most energy efficient way of acquaring and storing data from the accelerometer?